# How to make URL routing execute after StaticMiddleware in web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I have a URL route in my web.py application that I want to run to catch all URLs that hit the server, but only after any static assets are served.

For example, if theres is js/test.js in my `static` directory, the path `http://a.com/js/tests.js` should return the file contents. But I also have my url routing set up so that there is a regex that catches everything like this:

```
urls = ('/.*', 'CatchAllHandler')
```

So this should run *only* if no static asset was discovered. A request for `http://a.com/js/test.js` should return the static file `test.js`, but a request for `http://a.com/js/nope.js` should route through the `CatchAllHandler`.

I've looked into writing my own StaticMiddleware for this, but it will only help if the order of web.py operations is changed. Currently the middleware is executed after the URL routes have been processed. I need the middleware to run first, and let the url routing clean up the requests that were not served static assets.

The one idea I have is to use the notfound() function as my catch all handler, but that may not be best.

Answer (score 0):

the url matching is python [regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).  You can test/play with python regex [here](http://www.pythonregex.com/)

that said, this should work for you:

```
('/(?!static)(.*)', 'CatchAllHandler')
```

Comment: I ended up doing that, but it is not really the fix I wanted. I wanted to know if there was a way to let any middleware execute against requests before the URL routing is executed. That way it doesn't matter what url hosts the static files.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with web.py's middleware, but my understanding.. WSGI middleware happens before web.py gets to seeing the request/response.  I would think, provided your WSGI MiddleWare is properly configured, it would just work.

Comment: *pouts*  That sucks.  There is the add_handler stuff, which makes it really easy.. but I guess in regards to your other comment, 'wanting it to work regardless of URL'. How would you know it's static content otherwise?  I'm confused greatly.  The *EASIEST* way, since for production you want something like mod_wsgi running your web.py scripts, is to push all the static content into the web server.  Then you can of course do whatever you want in the web server that needs doing.

Answer (score 0):

*pouts*  That sucks.  There is the hook stuff, which makes it really easy, I've don't that before, and it will see all the stuff before ..   docs are here: http://webpy.org/cookbook/application_processors

but I guess in regards to your other comment, 'wanting it to work regardless of URL'. How would you know it's static content otherwise?  I'm confused greatly.  The *EASIEST* way, since for production you want some other web server running your web.py scripts, is to push all the static content into the web server.  Then you can of course do whatever you want in the web server that needs doing.  This is exactly what happens with mod_wsgi and apache for instance (you change /static to point to the directory *IN* the web server).

Perhaps if you shared an actual example of what you need done, I could help you more.  Otherwise I've given you now 3 different ways to handle the problem (excluding using WSGI middleware).  How many more do you need? :P